# What's the slickest way to create a comma-separated string of n instances of character c?

Tags: sql, groovy

In SQL statements, we often need to create a list of question marks that serve as parameters in an IN clause.  What's the shortest GROOVY expression to duplicate a question mark (or any character) n times and join them with commas to form a string?

Example:
expr('?', 3) would return "?,?,?"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't know if the slickest, but I like this:

```
assert (['?'] * 3).join(',') == '?,?,?'
```

The `* n` operation on a list returns a list equal to that list concatenated n times, so `['?'] * 3` equals `['?', '?', '?']`. Then the `.join(',')` just joins the elements of that list with a comma.

Comment: Any idea of a function similar to this in Microsoft SQL? Curiosity is eating away at me!

Comment: @Michael Wouldn't do you any good in TSQL unless you fed it to a dynamic exec. Anyway, Mitch Wheat posted a a deleted answer that contains: `declare @n int = 3; select SUBSTRING(REPLICATE ('?,', @n), 1, 2*@n - 1)`. YMMV.

Comment: This is another Groovy solution inspired in pst's comment: `('?,' * n)[0..-2]`. While this one is a bit shorter, I think the one propoed reads better. Still, may be taken in consideration for code golfing =D